# React Js Components imported but not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components 'footer' and 'header' in the components directory. It imports properly but I am not able to display it.

App.js

```
import header from "./components/header";
import footer from "./components/footer";

function App() {
 
  return (

    <>
      <header />
      <main>
          <h1>Welcome to Proshop</h1>
      </main>
      <footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

header.js

```
import React from 'react'

function header() {
  return (
    <div>header</div>
  )
}

export default header
```

footer.js

```
import React from 'react'

function footer() {
  return (
    <div>footer</div>
  )
}

export default footer
```

The output is just this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your components must start with a capital letter, if not they will be treated like a regular html tags, [see the docs on this](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

> When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a built-in component like `<div>` or `<span>` and results in a string 'div' or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a capital letter like `<Foo />` compile to React.createElement(Foo) and correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.

Bonus Point:

whatever your components file name is starting from the lower or uppercase letter you should always import it with an upper case.

let's say we have a file name header.js and a function with the name header.

it would help if you imported it like this

```
import Header from './header'
```

Comment: should I change it everywhere? like should I rename the components file name and component function? Thanks

Comment: Yes, all your components and render function should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

You should capitalize your component's name. For example: `<Header />`.

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me. I should only capitalize the tag name and the import.

Answer (score 0):

You should Capitalize your component's name. for example header will be : `<Header />` and footer will be `<Footer />`